# Getting MySQL Result-Set + LIMIT based off calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so I want to return data from a table based off of how closely identical they are.
So if all colums are an exact match thats 100%, if 9/10 match 90% etc...

I could just do

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

and then use a for loop in php or something placing each row at a higher index if its a greater match % but the problem with that is what if there arent 10 records but 100,000! that would make the script loading take forever...

So LIMIT wouldnt work with 100,000 records without somehow figuring out the match % in the SQL query which I cant figure out
Would it Involve the functions COUNT, SUM...?

Example Table:
(Users favorite things)

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------<br>
| id | color | food | cocktail | city | sport | <br>
+----------------------------------------------------------------<br>
| 1 | blue | pasta | cosmo | paris | football | <br>
| 2 | blue | burgers | lit | nyc | football | <br>
| 3 | green | hot dogs | negroni | nyc | football | <br>
| 4 | orange | sushi | manhattan | madrid | football | <br>
| 5 | purple | burgers | cosmo | paris | baseball | <br>
| 6 | red | sushi | lit | miami | basketball | <br>
| 7 | blue | sushi | cosmo | paris | football | <br>
| 8 | green | pasta | cosmo | madrid | baseball | <br>
| 9 | yellow | pasta | lit | paris | football |<br>
|10 | green | sushi | appletini | nyc | baseball |<br>
+------------------------------------------------------------------ <br>
```

A table this small wouldnt make a difference selecting all the records and sorting with PHP, but imagine if it was a LOT MORE 
**So say youre comparing WHERE id=1 and you want result set with LIMIT 5 where the 5 that are returned have the closest match (out of 5) to the first row?** 
So a user with blue | pasta | cosmo | paris | football | would have a 100% match 
and if this isnt possible with SQL, then what should i do with a large amount of records because a PHP for loop sorting the records would be very expensive performance wise...

*Sorry if this question was confusing or poorly written, I tried my best to explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
select ft.*
from favorite_things ft cross join
     favorite_things ft1
where ft1.id = 1 and ft1.id <> ft.id
order by ( (ft.color = ft1.color) +
           (ft.food = ft1.food) +
           (ft.cocktail = ft1.cocktail) +
           (ft.city = ft1.city) +
           (ft.sport = ft1.sport)
         ) desc
limit 5;
```

MySQL treats a boolean as a number in a numeric context, with 1 for "true" and 0 for "false".  So, summing the booleans counts the matches.

The rest is just `order by` and `limit`.

In other databases, you can do the same thing using `case` expressions.

Comment: Very nice solution :).

Comment: Should have known when I saw you edited the question that I wouldn't get a chance to answer! :)

Comment: You might want to exclude `ft.id = ft1.id`?

Comment: @Nick . . . That seems so reasonable that I added it in.